# How to get locale in Spring Websocket mapping

Tags: spring, websocket, locale

I have methods annotated with `@SubscribeMapping` and `@MessageMapping` in a Controller and I am unable to get the current locale from inside those methods.

How can I get the locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MessageMapping- with this annotation as method parameter you can use:

- @Message
- @Payload
- @Header
- @Headers
- @MessageHeaders

etc. Documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/MessageMapping.html).

You have at least three options, I will show you the first one:

```
@MessageMapping("/url1")
@SendTo("/url2")
public void sendMessage(@Payload String message, @Header(name = "locale", required = false, defaultValue = "en") String locale){
   Locale locale = new Locale(locale);
   //DO SOMETHING
}
```

You need to remember to set this header on the client side.